# Axum: Send image as response

Tags: rust, rust-axum

I'm currently trying to build an endpoint that will return an image (not in in bytes nor b64) to the user based on path but I cannot figure out how to do that with Axum and Rust.

The template of the method should look like that I guess:

```rs
#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct QueryParams {
    path: String,
}

pub async fn get_image(
    Query(QueryParams { path }): Query<QueryParams>
) -> impl IntoResponse {
}
```

And I already know the equivalent of what I want in C#

```cs
public ActionResult GetImage(string path)
{
    FileExtensionContentTypeProvider fileProvider = new();

    if (path.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        return NotFound("Parameter 'path' cannot be null or empty.");
    }
    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(path)))
    {
        return NotFound($"Folder '{Path.GetDirectoryName(path)}' not found.");
    }
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
        return NotFound($"File '{Path.GetFileName(path)}' not found.");
    }
    if (!fileProvider.TryGetContentType(path, out string? contentType))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
                $"Could not determine MIME type of {Path.GetFileName(path)}.");
    }

    return PhysicalFile(path, contentType);
}
```

I already tried to use the crate [image](https://crates.io/crates/image), [tower-http](https://crates.io/crates/tower-http) with the [ServeFile](https://docs.rs/tower-http/latest/tower_http/services/struct.ServeFile.html) struct but I can't figure out how to make it work properly.

If anyone could provide me some explanation or help it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [this discussion](https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/discussions/608) looks relevant

Comment: I've something now but it seems that in the new axum versions, the `response::Headers` seems like it doesn't exist anymore, any ideas where I can find that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer that came out from [this discussion](https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/discussions/608)

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct QueryParams {
    path: String,
}

pub async fn get_image(
    Query(QueryParams { path }): Query<QueryParams>
) -> impl IntoResponse {
    let filename = match PathBuf::from(path).file_name() {
        Some(name) => name,
        None => return Err((StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST, "File name couldn't be determined".to_string()))
    };
    let file = match tokio::fs::File::open(path).await {
        Ok(file) => file,
        Err(err) => return Err((StatusCode::NOT_FOUND, format!("File not found: {}", err)))
    };
    let content_type = match mime_guess::from_path(&path).first_raw() {
        Some(mime) => mime,
        None => return Err((StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST, "MIME Type couldn't be determined".to_string()))
    };

    let stream = ReaderStream::new(file);
    let body = StreamBody::new(stream);

    let headers = [
        (header::CONTENT_TYPE, content_type),
        (
            header::CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
            &format!("attachment; filename=\"{:?}\"", filename),
        ),
    ];
    Ok((headers, body))
}
```

Comment: This question was answered a while back but I forgot to answer it myself and left it opened ...